# Magento: Always redirecting me to "/downloader" path

Tags: php, html, magento

I hope you're good.

I have troubles with magento. A customer required me for migrating a magento website to another hosting service. I made the backup with cPanel tool (either database and public_html site with all the files uploaded).

When I restored all the site (and after change some folder and file permissions) and the database, the Magento site are always showing me the "Downloader" section and when I click to "continue magento installation", it returns to the downloader section.

In the console appears that all the files were already installed (doesn't throw me an error or issue) and in the cPanel logs doesn't appear any kind of issue

Can you help me pls? My customer are pursuing me with a torch and a kendo stick to solve this trouble D:

P.D. I tried using FTP, changing the file permissions in magento's downloader section to the same I have in the root directory (755 for folders and 644 for files) but I have in the lib folder 777 permissions, does it affect?

[image: The magento's downloader that are always showing me]

UPDATE

I have uploaded the snapshot I have in the hosting and It appears me the following exception

```
Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Exception' not found in /home/estetica/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Exception.php on line 34
```

So, when I printed all the classes that the framework is using and I found that the Zend/Db/Exception are loaded before the Zend/Exception class

So, where can I modify the order that the classes are imported by magento?

Comment: Did you follow the documentation https://magento2.atlassian.net/wiki/display/m1wiki/Moving+Magento+to+Another+Server

Comment: @RiggsFolly I've just finished of read the wiki you provided me. I don't have the old hosting services, I only have the public_html file in a backup file. But I will try to reinstall magento again and do the instructions in the wiki. Let me try this! Cheers!

Comment: Well if you don have the database then you are screwed

Comment: @RiggsFolly I know, but I have the database still alive and all the site. Let me try that